# How to load the pre-trained model of the tensorflow by using the opencv dnn model

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

The readNetFromTensorflow function fails to load the tensorflow pre-trained model (.pb).

Step 1: training the model of the tensorflow.
Tensorflow model of linear regression codes as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x_ = tf.placeholder(np.float32, [None, 1], 'input')
y_ = tf.placeholder(np.float32, [None, 1], 'label')
#layer1
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,3]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3]) )
a1 = tf.add(b1,tf.matmul(x_,w1)) 
#layer2
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,1]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]) )
a2 = tf.add(b2,tf.matmul(a1,w2),name="output") 
#global steps
steps = 5000 
x = []
y = []
for i in range(1,200,5):
    temp = (1.0 * i)/10
    x.append([temp])
    y.append([3. + 2. * temp])
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
#loss function
loss =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a2-y_)))
#optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.00001).minimize(loss)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    length = len(x)
    #training...
    for i in range(steps):
        sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x_:x,y_:y})
        result = sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x_:x,y_:y})
        if i % 50 == 0:
            print("loss: ",result,"\tstep: ",i)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess,"./model/model.ckpt")
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph.as_graph_def(), "./model/", "graph.pbtxt")
    print("predict...")
    pre = sess.run(a2,feed_dict={x_:[[0]]})
    print("x = 2 pre: ",pre)
```

Step 2: Save the model as the .pb file of the tensorflow. How to do that?

Step 3: Load the .pb file by using the function readNetFromTensorflow of the  opencv3.4.1 with C++. The codes like that:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace dnn;

std::vector<std::string> classes;

int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        cout<<"Usage: ./main [tensorflow modle path(.pb)]"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    String model = argv[1];
    Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow(model,argv[2]);
    cout<<"load Net OK!!"<<endl;

    float inp[1*1] = {2};
    Mat Matrix(1,1,CV_32FC1,inp);
    cout<<"Matrix:\n"<<Matrix<<endl;
    net.setInput(Matrix);

    Mat output = net.forward();
    cout<<"output: " << output <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result should be 7. 
There are two questions. First is how to generate a complete .pb file of the trained model, and another is how to use the pre-trained model in opencv3.4.1 dnn with C++?

Comment: For the `.pb` file, use the `freeze_graph.py` script on a checkpoint (look it up on Tensorflow's website for specifics of how to use it and what it does).

Comment: I have read the freeze_graph.py and uesd the method to generate the .pb file. The code to generate the .pb as following:   ~/tensorflow_source/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_graph model/graph.pbtxt --input_checkpoint model/model.ckpt --output_graph frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names "output" . However, there always appear a error in tf_importer.cpp when I run the C++ program metioned above to import the .pb file: Unknown layer type RandomStandardNormal in op random_normal/RandomStandardNormal in function populateNet.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what's happened to this program. The problem appears in Step 2.  It is essential to use the tensorflow function convert_variables_to_constants to transform the default graph to a new graph. Then using the tf.train.write_graph can save the old pre-trained model completely. Finally just modifing the codes in Step 2, the pre-trained model will be loaded successfully. The new codes of step 2 as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x_ = tf.placeholder(np.float32, [None, 1], 'input')
y_ = tf.placeholder(np.float32, [None, 1], 'label')
#layer1 
a1 = tf.layers.dense(input=x_,units=3,name="layer1") 
#layer2
a2 = tf.layers.dense(input=x_,units=1,name="layer2")
#global steps
steps = 5000 
x = []
y = []
for i in range(1,200,5):
    temp = (1.0 * i)/10
    x.append([temp])
    y.append([3. + 2. * temp])
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
#loss function
loss =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a2-y_)))
#optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.00001).minimize(loss)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    length = len(x)
    #training...
    for i in range(steps):
        sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x_:x,y_:y})
        result = sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x_:x,y_:y})
        if i % 50 == 0:
            print("loss: ",result,"\tstep: ",i)
     #save the .pbtxt file of the pre-trained model.
     tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph.as_graph_def(), "./model/", 
     #transfrom default graph  and save as a new graph.
     # the param 'output_node_names' should be the last op's name in the pre-trained model. In this model, last op's name is "layer2/BiasAdd" that found in the .pbtxt file like this:
     #node{
     #     name: "layer2/BiasAdd"
     #     op:   "BiasAdd"
     # .....
     output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess,sess.graph_def,output_node_names=['layer2/BiasAdd'])
     tf.train.write_graph(output_graph_def, "./model/", "graph.pbtxt",as_txt = False)
     print("predict...")
     pre = sess.run(a2,feed_dict={x_:[[0]]})
     print("x = 2 pre: ",pre)
```

The C++ codes are almost same with the above:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace dnn;

std::vector<std::string> classes;

int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        cout<<"Usage: ./main [tensorflow modle path(.pb)]"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    String model = argv[1];
    Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow(model,argv[2]);
    if(net.empty())
    {
        cout<<"load Net failed"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout<<"load Net OK!!"<<endl;
    float inp[1*1] = {0};
    Mat Matrix(1,1,CV_32FC1,inp);
    cout<<"Matrix:\n"<<Matrix<<endl;
    net.setInput(Matrix);

    Mat output = net.forward();
    #the value of the output should be equal to the output of the Step 1.
    cout<<"output: " << output <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Additionally,  when I using w1、b1 and w2、b2 instead of the tf.layers.dense to construct the network, there appears a error I don't understand for now:

```
Error: Unspecified error (More than one input is Const op) in getConstBlob, file /home/wy/Downloads/opencv 3.4.1/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp, line 571
```

Exception: OpenCV(3.4.1) /home/wy/Downloads/opencv-3.4.1/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:571: error: (-2) More than one input is Const op in function getConstBlob